# When should I use Nunjucks with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, nunjucks

I have been working with frameworks like backbone marionette, knockout and others... In those cases some times using handlebars or any other templating engine could be a good option.

When I am using Angular I found ng-repeat, ng-if and custom directives. Then I found Nunjucks that seems to be cool templating engine.

Is there any good reason to mix Angular with Nunjucks for a project?
Is there any benefit on using both in the same project?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as opinion based because there's benefits and drawbacks to both choices. Angular has it's own directives but Nunjucks might be easier to read for people with experience in other template engines.

Comment: May be the question is not well expressed, I was wondering if there is any scenario where you could take benefits on a templating engine like nunjucks with angularjs. I've seen boilerplates out there with both things but does not seems to be a good option. And there are many tools out there some times could be missleading how to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. AngularJS' double binding will take care of any templating need you might have. Nunjucks is static while AngularJS is dynamic. With Nunjucks, you need to process you file to render pages.

Comment: After doing some research I found that there are very rare cases where you can use both, and I believe your answer is correct as it applies to almost all scenarios, and mixing both things can be missleading in many cases. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I used Nunjucks with Gulp.js to itirate through an object to create static categories in a js file, then, Angular took that array as a const to build some app logic. You could use Nunjucks, but not for the data, Angular bindings are dynamic.